# Software to take notes for every realized telephone call

Tags: offline, note-taking, phone, contact-manager

I am looking for software to take notes for every telephone call I made.

- I would like to see a list of all realized calls with some particular contact
- Plus the possibility to show all the calls regardless of contacts
- Should also work offline
- Has to have (only) 4 to 10 important contact fields like Company, Name, Telephone, City - should be simple to use

I tried Outlook 2003, but the settings are very complicated, it has too many fields.
I tried some PIMs, but till now, no one has the possibility to add many dated notes to a contact.
I checked some Contact Management Software, but they are all complex (many of these programs are for companies, for online, for servers, etc.).

Do you know software that meets my requirements?

Comment: Why not use a basic note taking tool like notational velocity or Evernote and create a note for ever call? Choose a fixed format for a note title, and you will be able to search for all notes e.g. with "call to Kohomi" in the title. These notes get their timestamps, so you get a date sortable "call log".

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, a **contact manager** sounds like the best fit for your needs. Some of them are relatively easy to use, though any new software or tool with have at least a small learning curve.

[Insightly](https://www.insightly.com/) is pretty easy to use, especially if you use Gmail, and it offers a free plan that would probably work for you. The service would allow you to see calls for a certain contact or all contacts, assuming that you log them. It also can show only basic contact information, but also allows more detail in the future with custom fields if you ever need it. I don't think Insightly offers much offline access, however. If you're interested, this [help article](http://help.insightly.com/how-do-i-log-phone-call-notes-in-insightly/) outlines Insightly's recommendation for logging and reviewing calls.

You might also want to research [Zoho CRM](http://www.zoho.com/crm/) and [Nimble](http://www.nimble.com/), which are relatively straightforward and easy to use as well.

I will also echo the advice you received in a comment. A basic note-taking program like Evernote could address your issue if you strategically and systematically take notes.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder&hl=en). You never asked if you wanted to record your calls, but this app records them and allows you to then add notes to each log, the app integrates with the phones phonebook which is where you would have all your details you required.

The App contains:

- Search function based on name and/or number
- Full log (paid version to get more than 200 logs at any one time)
- Works offline, can set to *sync to cloud* (paid version).
- Phone phonebook would have the fields needed to record. App doesn't have this built in and relies on the phones ability.